# UIDatePicker show only specific days

Tags: swift, realm, uidatepicker

I have a Realm database where I store data, also with a date.
Therefore I want my DatePicker to hide basically all dates where NO entry is in the realm.
I will create an Array of Date-Strings which are stored in the realm database.
But how can I disable/enable only specific dates?

Of course I have set the maximum date to today with

```
datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
```

but for the entry in the past I want to disable all dates which there was no entry. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A date picker doesn't have any built-in functionality like that. You can set the minimum date and the maximum date, but that's all. You might have to create your own interface for letting the user pick a date, or change your interface specification to adapt to what's easily possible.

Comment: Can this be achieved with adding a UIPickerViewDelegate with `pickerView attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:`? I haven't tried it, but I recall the UIDatePicker being a subclass or UIPickerView. Just a thought.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to highlight certain days in the datepicker?